# I can't install gem locomotivecms because of dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, locomotivecms

As it says in the photo, locomotivecms_steam's latest version needs Ruby < 3 but all the stable versions of Ruby are > 3. How can I installed locomotivecms? I'm using https://doc.locomotivecms.com/docs/quick-start but it's not helping me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCHc4.png)

I'm using the gemfile and bundler install to do it. I also tried with the command

```
    gem install locomotivecms_wagon
    It was installed but when I type
```

wagon version

```
It says is 1.58 but i need 3.0.2 at least and I don't know hot to update it.

This is my gemfile and gemfile.lock
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmG9V.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL7bm.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlF1o.png)
```

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as photographs of text. This is a website for programmers, not photographers. We want to copy&paste&run your code, copy&paste your inputs, read your outputs, and copy&paste&google your error messages, not critique your use of color and perspective. Also, please make sure to post everything relevant to answering your question *in your question*, not behind a link. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2988 https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: "all the stable versions of Ruby are > 3" – Ruby 2.7 is still in the "security maintenance" phase and will be supported probably for the next 2.5 months. (End-of-life is always somewhere around the beginning of April.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is: You cannot run it with Ruby 3.

When the `locomotivecms` gem has a dependency to `locomotivecms_steam` gem and even the latest version of `locomotivecms_steam` does not support Ruby 3.0 yet, then you will need to downgrade your Ruby version to `2.7.7`.

There haven't been many releases `locomotivecms_steam` in the last years, which makes it unlikely that they will fix this dependency problem soon.

That means your options are:

- Downgrade to ruby `2.7.7` was released [recently](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2022/11/24/ruby-2-7-7-released/), which means it is not fully unmaintained yet, but it will reach end-of-life in about 2 months at end of March 2023.
- Or you might want to consider forking the gem and fixing it yourself to make it run with Ruby 3.x. It might be easy, and the gem has only a few incompatibilities with Ruby. But it is also possible that this would be hard and therefore hasn't been done by the maintainers yet.

In both cases, I suggest looking for alternatives, because depending on a gem that is not actively maintained anymore or that you have to maintain on your own, doesn't sound like a good idea.